# Chrome sluggish when Eclipse is open

Tags: google-chrome, java, eclipse

I'm having the oddest issue with Eclipse and Chrome.

If I have the Eclipse IDE open, Chrome get's really sluggish. Just moving the mouse over link type elements in Chrome 'causes a sluggish mouse response and a spike in my CPU usage with activity on the javaw.exe process. I'm no where near CPU (2% nothing else running in the background, latest i7 processor) or memory limited (16GB of which only 30% is used).

The problem disappears the moment I close Eclipse. Other Java applications (like Java's own control panel which also spawns the javaw.exe process) don't seem to cause this interference. I have no additional extensions / plugins installed in Chrome or Eclipse.

This doesn't happen with Firefox. Moving the Eclipse installation location doesn't seem to help either. I'm on the latest versions of Java 7 (can't switch to 8 yet for various development reasons), Firefox, and Eclipse.
Would appreciate any clues anyone can provide!

Comment: How much RAM do you have in your system? Eclipse and Chrome combined can take up a lot of RAM.

Comment: 16GB of which both Eclipse and Chrome aren't taking up more than 1.5GB, and I still have 60% free even with the other process / background operations running on the system.

Comment: Do you have any Java applets open in Chrome? It *shouldn't* matter, but Eclipse is a Java program so maybe something could impact that...

Comment: @CBHacking No, I have no Java applets or anything open in Chrome. I don't have any extensions running either. Just opening up a stackexchange page for example, the mouse-over becomes sluggish